# Is there any easily plug-gable official RBAC implementation for .NET framework?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

We are building to many applications in .NET (specially .NET-core) framework. Most of them are in C#. The problem is, each developer is implementing their own RBAC implementation in their projects. At the end we have too many form of RBAC implementations.

Is they any official or community supported de-facto implementations of RBAC in .NET (C#) that we can re-use in all our projects.

Please share if you feel any good practice as well in this regard.

Comment: This question is too broad, subjective and offtopic. But for me when it comes to "authentication" and "authorization" I think about `ASP.Net Identity` and `IdentityServer4`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ASP.NET Identity.`

More about ASP.NET Identity at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/

Comment: We are using C# not ASP. Identity is specific to ASP I think. Is that correct?

Comment: @rayhan, no, it is specific for ASP.Net, but you can use it anywhere

Comment: you can use it database and service